# Output part of a tuple in python

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples and I would like to output one piece of them to an output file. The list is a ranked list that looks like the following:

```
[('a', 2), ('b', 1)]
```

and I would like to output just the numbers to a file so the output file would look like:

```
2
1
```

Currently I'm using something like this but it outputs the entire tuple:

```
outputFile.write('\n'.join('%s %s' % x for x in List))
```

Comment: Are they all of the format `(letter, number)`?

Comment: yes they are all that format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

outputFile.write('\n'.join(str(y) for x,y in List))